# How do i assign the value " "hello" " to a string?

Tags: java, string

I want the quotes (`"`) to be a part of the string. i.e.    `System.out.println(myString);`
should output    `"hello"`
and not just    `hello`

Comment: use \" to specify quote.  what a trivial question that you can just google and quickly get an answer.  watch the # of answers... that say exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 11):

You must escape the quotes :

```
String myString = "\"hello\"";
```

[This page of the Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) gives all needed details regarding string literals and escape sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Add `escape character (\)` with your double quotes. `"\"hello\""`.